# How to get as byte[] using JPQL in spring-jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, service

I can save as blob easily in database using jpa-repository(Hibernate) in spring.Field of written column blob  as byte[] array. Get from this database using the same saved entity is easy.But when try to use jpql query which written in jpa repository showed for me this blob column as bigInteger.why? I saved it byte[] array.How I can get from this column using jpql query as byte. When try to implement following errors gives in postman.How I could retrieve it as byte[] array using jpa repository with help of query ?

```
        "message": "Could not write JSON: Failed to convert from type 
    [java.math.BigInteger] to type [byte] for value '98818'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert number [98818] of type 
[java.math.BigInteger] to target class [java.lang.Byte]: overflow; nested 
exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to 
convert from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [byte] for value '98818'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert number
 [98818] of type [java.math.BigInteger] to target class [java.lang.Byte]: 
overflow (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-
>com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104[\"image\"])",
```

**Repository**

```
public interface AirLinesRepository extends JpaRepository<AirLinesEntity,Long>
{
    @Query(value = "select air_lines.image,air_lines.name_airline from air_lines",nativeQuery = true)
    List<OtherDto> getAllmost();
}
```

**ServiceImpl class**

```
 @Override
    public List<OtherDto> yes()
    {
        List<OtherDto> yep = airLinesRepository.getAllmost();
        return yep;
    }
```

**OtherDto class**

```
public interface OtherDto {
     String getName_airline();
     byte[] getImage();
}
```

[image]
image colum targeted as BigInteger (oid) type of column

**How could retrieve this image column as byte [] using spring-jpa ?**